# Prevent embedded YouTube player from plating onclick

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

When you embed a YouTube video in a page, there is a big play button in the middle of it which plays the video when clicked. For example:

[image: example of button]

Is there a way that I can capture this click event before it plays the video and divert it to do something else?

Comment: If you use the JS API you can do pretty much anything.

Comment: Only if "anything" doesn't include preventing the video from playing onclick ;)

Comment: Well you could overlay the video, or not even show the video (just a poster image) and add your own click event that starts playing the video as well as whatever else you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put something on top of it..it can link or execute some code
If Youtube player is Flash ..then you need to add the parameter
wmode=transparent to the player embed-code
this will prevent the Flash to stay on top.

Officially its against Youtube´s rules (T.O.S.) to overlay anything on top
even worse if it misleads the visitor...who thinks he will play the video
but gets redirected to something else.
Make at least shure that clicking the play-video button will indeed play that video.

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything shady. I'm building my own play/pause button but the fact that clicking the video makes it play means that there is two ways to play the video and it makes the program far more complicated. So basically I want to detect a click on the video then delegate to my own method to play the video. The user won't even notice.

Comment: If they detect it (no idea if they are still actively checking)     they might not spend the time to investigate that your way is  actually harmless...anyway you could create a fake player (pic) in a iframe...put your not-real playbutton on it and do what you wanna do, Or you could instead set the player to not show controlbar and make your own playbutton below it (using js api control) https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference